# Action induces action of group ring on singular chain complex.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511450/cw-complex-such-that-action-induces-action-of-group-ring-on-cellular-chain-compl) for a related question.

Let $X$ be a space that satisfies the hypotheses used to construct a universal cover $\overline{X}$. Let $\pi = \pi_1(X)$ and consider the action of the group $\pi$ on the space $\overline{X}$ given by the isomorphism of $\pi$ with $\text{Aut}(\overline{X})$. Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ act trivially on $A$, $a \cdot \sigma = a$ for $\sigma \in \pi$ and $a \in A$.

How do I see that the action of $\pi$ on $\overline{X}$ induces an action of $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ on the singular chain complex $C_*(\overline{X})$ such that each $C_q(\overline{X})$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-module and$$C_*(X; A) \cong A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi]} C_*(\overline{X})?$$

Answer (score 0):

To construct the singular chain complex of $\overline{X}$ you can construct the singular chain complex of X and lift it with the universal covering map $p:\overline{X}\rightarrow X$.

A n-simplex of $X$ is defined by a morphism $f:\Delta_n\rightarrow X$ which can be lifted to $f':\Delta_n\rightarrow\overline{X}$ since $p$ is a Serre fibration, you can make $\pi$ acts by composition with the Deck transformations